# ffmpeg mkv to mp4 muxed subs and .srt

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mkv

So I'm trying to remux different folders with mkv.
Some of the mkv have subtitles muxed into mkv.
Others have a seperate .srt file

This is the command im using for converting mkv to mp4 and ac3

```
for i in *.mkv; do
ffmpeg -i "$i" -i *.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -c:a ac3 -ac 6 -b:a 640k "${i%.mkv*}.mp4"
done
```

I'm dont get result I want since some of the .srt files are named incorretly and the muxed in subtitles all get named MOV_TEXT

Comment: Your command is strange: `ffmpeg -i "$i" -i *.srt`. For example, you have two files in your folder: 1.srt and 2.srt. In a bash, this will lead to `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i 1.srt 2.srt -c copy ...` .. so ffmpeg will use 1.srt as input file, but 2.srt as output file name. How are the files organized?

Comment: Folder 1: (with subtitles muxed)
movie.mkv

Folder 2: (Separate .srt)
1.srt
movie.mkv